# Can NHibernate work with 2 different schema?

Tags: nhibernate

Can NHibernate work with 2 different schema? I have a project to work with say Schema `A` for few parts and Schema `B` for others. Is this possible with NHibernate? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible, but you'll have to instantiate 2 session factories.

Perhaps [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/NHibernateMultipleDBs.aspx?msg=2529595) article can be helpfull

Answer (score 6):

If these schemata are in the same database, you can specify it in the mapping file:

```
<class name="MyClass" schema="A">
...
</class>

<class name="AnotherClass" schema="B">
...
</class>
```